# OS partition going into read only mode multiple times per day, help me decipher the dmesg log

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, fsck, read-only

Latest Ubuntu on new M2 ssd. Fresh install.
Goes into read only mode a few times each day.
Reboot in recovery and `fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root/` fixes it (encrypted drive and home dir)

`fsck -Af -M` doesn't return anything.

Here is the output of `dmesg` right after going into read only:

```
[27124.116446] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27124.116451] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000010f629])
[27124.116841] loop: Write error at byte offset 4552953856, length 4096.
[27124.116846] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8892488
[27124.116852] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262287 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 1111562)
[27124.116857] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 1111561
[27124.786795] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27124.786803] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000010f629])
[27124.786934] loop: Write error at byte offset 4552953856, length 4096.
[27124.786938] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8892488
[27124.786942] EXT4-fs warning (device loop0): ext4_end_bio:314: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262287 (offset 0 size 0 starting block 1111562)
[27124.786944] Buffer I/O error on device loop0, logical block 1111561
[27124.787480] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27124.787484] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
[27126.042348] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.042354] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afdf])
[27126.042546] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626734080, length 4096.
[27126.042556] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942840
[27126.042754] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.042757] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe0])
[27126.042903] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626738176, length 4096.
[27126.042908] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942848
[27126.042997] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.042999] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe1])
[27126.043075] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626742272, length 4096.
[27126.043077] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942856
[27126.043168] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.043170] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe2])
[27126.043229] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626746368, length 4096.
[27126.043232] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942864
[27126.043307] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.043309] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe3])
[27126.043381] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626750464, length 4096.
[27126.043384] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942872
[27126.045927] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.045930] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe4])
[27126.046063] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626754560, length 4096.
[27126.046067] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942880
[27126.046146] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.046149] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe5])
[27126.046225] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626758656, length 4096.
[27126.046228] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942888
[27126.046284] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.046287] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe6])
[27126.046350] loop: Write error at byte offset 6626762752, length 4096.
[27126.046351] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 12942896
[27126.046396] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.046398] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe7])
[27126.048075] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048078] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe8])
[27126.048271] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048277] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afe9])
[27126.048374] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048376] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afea])
[27126.048469] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048471] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afeb])
[27126.048670] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048672] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afec])
[27126.048774] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048776] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afed])
[27126.048929] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.048931] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afee])
[27126.049077] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049079] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018afef])
[27126.049180] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049182] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018aff0])
[27126.049271] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049273] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018aff1])
[27126.049371] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049373] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000018aff2])
[27126.049438] Aborting journal on device loop0-8.
[27126.049577] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049579] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000020])
[27126.049640] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[27126.049651] EXT4-fs error (device loop0): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[27126.049654] EXT4-fs (loop0): Remounting filesystem read-only
[27126.049656] EXT4-fs (loop0): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[27126.049728] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049730] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000188361])
[27126.049787] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1606465, lost sync page write
[27126.049792] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for loop0-8.
[27126.049872] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27126.049877] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000020])
[27126.049939] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[27127.297578] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27127.297580] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27127.384213] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27127.384217] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27129.642205] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.642212] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000000362])
[27129.642453] lo_write_bvec: 15 callbacks suppressed
[27129.642456] loop: Write error at byte offset 3416064, length 4096.
[27129.642461] blk_update_request: 18 callbacks suppressed
[27129.642463] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 6672
[27129.642469] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 834, lost async page write
[27129.649180] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.649188] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000080022])
[27129.649465] loop: Write error at byte offset 2147491840, length 4096.
[27129.649475] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 4194320
[27129.649481] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 524290, lost async page write
[27129.649650] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.649655] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000080026])
[27129.649930] loop: Write error at byte offset 2147508224, length 4096.
[27129.649942] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 4194352
[27129.649952] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 524294, lost async page write
[27129.650177] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.650182] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000008002b])
[27129.650338] loop: Write error at byte offset 2147528704, length 4096.
[27129.650343] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 4194392
[27129.650347] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 524299, lost async page write
[27129.650455] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.650460] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000100021])
[27129.650593] loop: Write error at byte offset 4294971392, length 4096.
[27129.650598] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8388616
[27129.650602] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048577, lost async page write
[27129.650704] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.650707] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000100047])
[27129.650814] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295127040, length 4096.
[27129.650818] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8388920
[27129.650821] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048615, lost async page write
[27129.650919] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.650923] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000010004a])
[27129.651038] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295139328, length 4096.
[27129.651043] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8388944
[27129.651046] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 1048618, lost async page write
[27129.651136] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.651139] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000010004b])
[27129.651241] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295143424, length 4096.
[27129.651245] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8388952
[27129.651356] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.651360] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000100079])
[27129.651528] loop: Write error at byte offset 4295331840, length 4096.
[27129.651532] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8389320
[27129.651668] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.651672] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000001095ae])
[27129.651771] loop: Write error at byte offset 4451786752, length 4096.
[27129.651775] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 8694896
[27129.651873] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.651878] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000300020])
[27129.652117] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27129.652120] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x0000000000300022])
[27183.393671] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27183.393675] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27184.696575] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27184.696580] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27184.914157] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27184.914165] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27384.495501] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27384.495504] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27387.323486] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27387.323491] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27387.410101] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27387.410103] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27543.669165] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27543.669169] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27546.684444] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27546.684447] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27546.927912] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27546.927921] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27578.543071] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27578.543074] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27578.819683] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27578.819686] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27578.819891] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27578.819894] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27583.807481] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27583.807489] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27583.919273] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27583.919277] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 169: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27587.449609] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27587.449611] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27589.612009] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27589.612017] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27589.618925] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27589.618933] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27589.619730] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27589.619737] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27589.620993] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27589.621001] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27591.793296] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-1): ext4_dirent_csum_verify:352: inode #13502225: comm Cache2 I/O: No space for directory leaf checksum. Please run e2fsck -D.
[27591.793298] EXT4-fs error (device dm-1): ext4_dx_find_entry:1532: inode #13502225: block 226: comm Cache2 I/O: Directory block failed checksum
[27819.658524] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27819.658528] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
[27950.833264] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[27950.833271] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
[28164.666643] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[28164.666660] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
[28250.832180] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[28250.832194] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
[28288.554615] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-30]
[28288.554620] ecryptfs_write_end: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x00000000000003cb])
```

Comment: I'd check the M2 SSD manufacturer's web site for a firmware update. I'd also use the `Disks` app `SMART Data & Tests` to review the SMART data and to run the tests. You could also install `gsmartcontrol` to monitor the drive. I'd run `fsck -f /` from the recovery mode/root access prompt to correctly fsck the drive.

Comment: Thanks. Have been doing only fsck until now wiht no parameters, and just now I read that this checks only the journal when no -f is included. lol. Stupid me. 
For some reason I don't have smart data & tests for this drive. It's grayed out in Disks. I have it for a usb attached disk though.

Comment: Check the SSD firmware.

Comment: No idea how to do that, but will look into it. Thank you! :)

Comment: Get the make/model # of your SSD. Go to the manufacturer's web site. Look under `support`. Enter your model # in the search box. Look for a firmware update.